# context.Response.Redirect from a handler does not works

Tags: c#, handler, httpcontext, response.redirect

I'm trying to do the following : 
- Call thru JQuery a function on a handler, 
- once the treatment is done, redirect to a page.

The issue is that the page does not seems to be load.

I made the following code in order to be clearest.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js""></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function CallHandler() {
      console.info("Entering CallHandler");
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "Handlers/MyFunction.ashx",
          data: { helloworld: 'hello world'},
          success: function (data) {
              console.info(data);
              }
          });
      }

    </script>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="linkForTest" onclick='CallHandler();' Text='Click Me'     />            
</asp:Content>
```

and my handler is like the following :

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MyFunction
/// </summary>
public class MyFunction : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(context.Request["HelloWorld"]);
        context.Response.Redirect("~/Login/WebForm1.aspx");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It should called my page "Login/Webform1.aspx", but it calls nothing. 
However, Firebug dont seems to find an issue... just it keeps trying to load a page... And failed.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure a redirect in response to an ajax request will not redirect the host page.  There are several ways to handle this.  One way is you can do a client side redirect in response to some sort of notification or status code from your handler.

Comment: The solution I found, for the moment (I suppose there is a better way) is to return a value (thru Json), which is check by the Javascript page, which redirect to the good page (~/Login/login.aspx). It is I think a crappy code, but it is working...

Answer (score 0):

it's looping?

is it redirecting even when its on the page its redirecting to?

maybe you need to check the context.Request.Url before redirecting

Comment: Its looping yes. The request.Url is correct. A colleague told me the issue was coming from the fact I'm trying to make the redirection of the page FROM the handler, and not from the calling page.

Comment: so if you are already on the page that you want to redirect to, don't call the redirect if(!request.Url.EndsWith("Login/WebForm1.aspx")) context.Response.Redirect("~/Login/WebForm1.aspx");

Comment: I am not on this page. I am on the page actually : "~/Default/Default.aspx" and I want to go to "~/Login/Login.aspx".

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the handler `helloworld` and reading it as `HelloWorld` see if that's a null reference error? Also, use an error handler on the $.ajax call and see if it is being thrown.

```
  console.info("Entering CallHandler");
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "Handlers/MyFunction.ashx",
      data: { HelloWorld: 'hello world'},
      success: function (data) {
          console.info(data);
          },
      error: function (data) {
          console.error(data);
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: No null reference. And the application never going thru console.info, success or error... Because of the redirect I suppose...

Comment: I don't quite get the purpose of writing "Hello World" then redirecting the Request, are you trying to redirect the user to the login page? if so, then you should respond with "unauthorized" and possibly the location to log in then have javascript set `location.href`. If you are trying to dynamically load the login form into a div or something then you could try `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect`

Comment: Hello world is just an example of my code. A way to write I'm transferring data without any issue. What in real my page is doing, it is registering a user thru Facebook account, and once it is register logged in, it is actually redirect to a default page you can not access if you are not a member. But I wanted a simple example, thats why I wrote this example.

Comment: I would do exactly what you said you are doing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209327/context-response-redirect-from-a-handler-does-not-works/10209383#comment13134396_10219470)

Comment: Hope there will have a better solution... Thanks however for your help.

Answer (score 0):

when redirecting, the content of the page you want to redirect will be passed as ajax result.

Answer (score 0):

you can call response.redirect another way by client side call using javascript

```js
console.info("Entering CallHandler");
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "Handlers/MyFunction.ashx",
      data: { HelloWorld: 'hello world'},
      success: function (data) {
                   window.location.href ="WebForm1.aspx"  ;
          },
      error: function (data) {
          console.error(data);
          }
      });
  }
```